# How to stop the GNUradio flowgraph after a specified time?

Tags: gnuradio-companion

I am new to GNUradio and I am making a FM Receiver. I am recording the data into the file sink. But I need the data of just 1 millisecond. How can I specify this time so that my flowgraph automatically stop after this time?

I also read some solutions regarding the calling of stop() and start() methods and I tried that in GRC generated python file also but it didn't work for me, may be I made a mistake.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use the "Head" block to stop after passing the 1ms·sample rate of samples.